# windows desktop icone moves from primary monitor to secondary monitor on extended mode

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I am currently trying to extend my POS display onto secondary monitor, but all I am getting is all my desktop icone also extend to second display and left my primary monitor empty (the windows logo with the snapshot of the default windows desktop background on the primary monitor. Any ideas on how to configure it properly would be appreciated.

Comment: I very well may be wrong, but that sounds like the extended desktop was configured as the primary desktop, reversing what normally would occur. The setting should either be in the GPU settings application, the Windows display, or GPU driver, settings.

Comment: should i remove the driver and install it again cause i search on the GPU settings every thing its normal

Comment: Re-installing the GPU driver is unlikely to resolve the issue if the GPU driver application and/or driver settings do not have that setting in their respective settings applications. If using Windows 10, is that setting not in _Settings_ → _System_ → _Display_? I know I've come across the setting to make an extended desktop the primary before, but can't recall precisely where that setting is at... I would also try google.

Comment: what can do to resolve it i've tried much ways and nothing yes